# Checking to see if 2 numbers in array sum to 0 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I've been going at this problem for a few hours, and I can't see why I can't get it to run properly.  The end game to this method is having 2 numbers in an array equaling zero when added together. Here is my code:

```
def two_sums(nums)
    i = 0
    j = -1
    while i < nums.count
        num_1 = nums[i]
        while j < nums.count
        num_2 = nums[j]
            if num_1 + num_2 == 0
                return "There are 2 numbers that sum to zero & they are #{num_1} and #{num_2}."
            else
                return "Nothing adds to zero."
            end             
        end
    i += 1
    j -= 1
    end
end
```

The problem I'm having is unless the first and last number in the array are the positive and negative of the same number, this will always return false.

For example, if I had an array that was [1, 4, 6, -1, 10], it should come back true.  I'm sure my 2 while statement is the cause of this, but I can't think of a way to fix it.  If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

You can find the first pair that adds up to 0 like this:

```
nums.combination(2).find { |x, y| x + y == 0 }
#=> returns the first matching pair or nil
```

Or if you want to select all pairs that add up to 0:

```
nums.combination(2).select { |x, y| x + y == 0 }
#=> returns all matching pairs or an empty array
```

Therefore you can implement your method like this:

```
def two_sums(nums)
  pair = nums.combination(2).find { |x, y| x + y == 0 }
  if pair
    "There are 2 numbers that sum to zero & they are #{pair.first} and #{pair.last}."
  else
    "Nothing adds to zero."
  end
end
```

Or if you want to find all pairs:

```
def two_sums(nums)
  pairs = nums.combination(2).select { |x, y| x + y == 0 }
  if pairs.empty?
    "Nothing adds to zero."
  else
    "The following pairs sum to zero: #{pairs}..."
  end
end
```

Comment: For small cases this is fine. But as these methods are O(n^2) if you have large cases you'll want a O(nlogn) or O(n) method

Comment: You are absolutely right @JKillian. Sorting the array first and having pointers from both ends of the array looking for matching pairs would be more efficient. But in my opinion this question was about making the code working and readable, not about improving runtime.

Comment: Agreed, your answer works fine for the majority of situations. I posted an answer using a hash for fun (and theoretical efficiency).

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way:

**Code**

```
def sum_to_zero(arr)
  arr.group_by { |e| e.abs }
     .values
     .select { |a| (a.size > 1 && a.first == 0) || a.uniq.size > 1 }
end
```

**Examples**

```
sum_to_zero [1, 4, 6, -1, 10]     #=> [[1, -1]]
sum_to_zero [1, 4, 1, -2, 10]     #=> []
sum_to_zero [1, 0, 4,  1,  0, -1] #=> [[1, 1, -1], [0, 0]]
```

This method is relatively fast. Let's try it with an array of 200,000 elements, each a random number between -500,000 and 500,000.

```
require 'time'

t = Time.now
arr = Array.new(200_000) { rand(1_000_001) - 500_000 }
arr.size #=> 200000

sum_to_zero(arr).size #=> 16439
Time.now - t
  #=> 0.23 (seconds) 

sum_to_zero(arr).first(6)
  #=> [[-98747, 98747],
  #    [157848, -157848],
  #    [-459650, 459650],
  #    [176655, 176655, -176655],
  #    [282101, -282101],
  #    [100886, 100886, -100886]]
```

If you wish to group the non-negative and negative values that sum to zero:

```
sum_to_zero(arr).map { |a| a.partition { |e| e >= 0 } }.first(6)
  #=> [[[98747], [-98747]],
  #    [[157848], [-157848]],
  #    [[459650], [-459650]],
  #    [[176655, 176655], [-176655]],
  #    [[282101], [-282101]],
  #    [[100886, 100886], [-100886]]]
```

If you only want a single value for each group (a non-negative value, say):

```
sum_to_zero(arr).map { |a| a.first.abs }.first(6)
  #=> [98747, 157848, 459650, 176655, 282101, 100886]
```

Comment: Neat method, this should be linear time as well I think, because group_by should be linear and .uniq should only have to traverse each value once in total so should be linear time as well. Just as a tiny nitpick, I believe the `a.size > 1` condition is redundant in your main method definition

Comment: @JKillan, we do have to ensure that, to be included, the size of an array containing zeros must be at least two.  What I have can be improved, however, and I've made the fix.  Thanks for the mention.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most Ruby way would be:

```
nums.combination(2).any? { |x,y| (x+y).zero? }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that should work well for large arrays. The methods above which go through every possible combination of two numbers are perfectly fine for small cases but will be very slow and memory hungry for arrays with lots of elements.

```
def two_sums nums
  h = Hash.new
  nums.each do |n|
    return true if h[-n]
    h[n] = true
  end
  false
end
```

Comment: I feel like this code is pretty ugly! Any ideas to make it look nicer but keep it functionally the same?

Comment: Very nice! I modified it to return all n >= 0 that satisfy the summing to zero requirement and ran it against the random array of 200,000 elements I gave in my answer. It was lightning fast! Here's the code: `h = {}; nums.each_with_object([]) { |n,a| h[n] = true; a << n if h[-n] }.map(&:abs).uniq`, `two_sums(arr).first(6) #=> [361248, 209826, 277499, 324861, 56859, 112086]`.

Comment: Make that `require 'set'; nums.each_with_object(Set.new) { |n,s| h[n] = true; s << n.abs if h[-n] }.to_a`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, given it's tagged as #ruby, here's the most "ruby way" I could think of tackling this problem:

```
def two_sums(arr)
  numbers = arr.combination(2).select { |a| a.reduce(:+) == 0 }.flatten

  if numbers.empty?
    "Nothing adds to zero."
  else
    "There are 2 numbers that sum to zero & they are #{numbers.first} and #{numbers.last}."
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, I'm still pretty new to Ruby, so I recognize 90% of the code.  Haven't gotten to the .reduce or .combination yet.  Thanks for your help wicz!  :)

Comment: Since you know that `a` is a two elements array, using `a.reduce(:+)` is a very complex way to calculate `x+y`. Just do `select { |x,y| x+y == 0 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
array.combination(2).select{|x|x[0] + x[1] == 0}
```