# How to optimize the solution for Two_sum code in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am woking on the solution for the following question.

```
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution.

Example:
Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9,

Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9,
return [0, 1].
```

This is the solution submitted in ruby after referring the C++ code http://leetcodeunlock.com/2016/05/20/leetcode-1-two-sum-easy/ .

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
hash = {}
arr = []
nums.each_with_index do |value,index|
    y = target - value
    if(hash.find{|key,val| key == value})
        arr << hash[value]
        arr << index
        return arr
    else
     hash[y] = index
    end
end
end
```

My submission failed with the message : Time limit exceeded. Can anyone point out the mistake and help me optimise the code?

Comment: I think a big issue is that you are potentially traversing a large hash for almost every value in the `nums` array. Try starting off with a way to maintain indices, then sort the array and work your way down from both ends.

Comment: Have a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213818/checking-to-see-if-2-numbers-in-array-sum-to-0-in-ruby) for ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified the line 
    ***if(hash.find{|key,val| key == value})***
to 
     ***if(hash.key?(value))*** 
to find if a specific key is present in the hash and this solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
nums = [2, 7, 11, 15]
target = 9

# this will find all combinations of 2 elements that add up to 9 
results = (0...nums.size).to_a.combination(2).select { |first, last| nums[first] + nums[last] == target }

results.first #=> [0, 1]
```

Explanation of some parts of the code:

```
# Get indexes of all elements of nums array
(0...nums.size).to_a #=> [0, 1, 2, 3]

# Generate all combinations of indexes of each 2 elements
(0...nums.size).to_a.combination(2).to_a #=>  [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: This solution fails with the same error: Time limit exceeded

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
def sum_to_num(arr, num)
  return [num/2, num/2] if num.even? && arr.count(num/2) > 1 
  a = arr.uniq.
          group_by { |n| (2*n-num).abs }.
          find { |_,a| a.size > 1 }
  a.nil? ? nil : a.last
end
```

This method requires three or four passes through the array, if `num` is even, one to count the instances of `num/2`, one to remove duplicate values, one to `group_by` and one to `find` the pair of numbers that sum to the desired total. It therefore should be much faster than methods that evaluate every pair of the array's elements, particularly as the size of the array is increased.

**Examples**

```
sum_to_num [2, 11, 7, 15], 9
  #=> [2, 7] 
sum_to_num [2, 5, 2, 6, 1, -5, 4], 10
  #=> [6, 4]
sum_to_num [2, 7, 11, -7, 15], 0
  #=> [7, -7] 
sum_to_num [2, 7, 11, 7, 15], 14 #???
sum_to_num [2, -7, 11, -7, 15], -14 #???
sum_to_num [2, 7, 11, 15], 17
  #=> [2, 15] 
sum_to_num [2, -11, 8, 15], 4
  #=> [-11, 15] 
sum_to_num [2, -11, 8, 15], -3
  #=> [-11, 8] 
sum_to_num [2, -11, 8, 15], 100
  #=> nil
```

**Explanation**

Assume `x` and `y` sum to `num`. Then

```
2*x-num + 2*y-num = 2*(x+y) - 2*num
                  = 2*num - 2*num 
                  = 0
```

meaning that `2*x-num` and `2*y-num` are either both zero or they have the opposite signs and the same absolute value. Similarly, if `2*x-num` and `2*y-num` sum to zero, then

```
2*x-num + 2*y-num = 0
2*(x+y) - 2*num = 0
```

meaning that `n+m = num` (which is hardly surprising considering that `2*x+num` is a linear transformation.

Suppose

```
arr = [2, 5, 2, 6, 1, -5, 4]
num = 10
```

then

```
 if num.even? && arr.count(num/2) > 1
   #=> if 10.even? && arr.count(5) > 1
   #=> if true && false
   #=> false
```

Therefore, do not return `[5,5]`.

```
 b = arr.uniq
   #=> [2, 5, 6, 1, -5, 4]
 c = b.group_by { |n| (2*n-num).abs }
   #=> {6=>[2], 0=>[5], 2=>[6, 4], 8=>[1], 20=>[-5]} 
 a = c.find { |_,a| a.size > 1 }
   #=> [2, [6, 4]] 
 return nil if a.nil?
   # do not return
 a.last
   #=> [6, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I was doing this challenge for fun and wrote a cleaned up ruby solution.

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
    hash = {}
    nums.each_with_index { |number, index| hash[number] = index }

    nums.each_with_index do |number, index|
        difference = target - number 
        if hash[difference] && hash[difference] != index
            return [index, hash[difference]]  
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
# @param {Integer[]} nums
# @param {Integer} target
# @return {Integer[]}
def two_sum(nums, target)
    length = nums.length 
    for i in 0..length
        j = i+1 
       for a in j..length
          if j < length
            if nums[i] + nums[a] == target
               return [i, a]          
           end
          end
       j+=1
      end
    end
  []
end
```

Well this is my way of solving this

Comment: Please also give some explanation of what the code does.

Answer (score 0):

```
def two_sum(nums, target)
  nums.each_with_index do |value, index|
    match_index = nums.find_index(target - value)
    return [index, match_index] if match_index
  end
  nil
end
```

The above has the advantage that it stops execution when a match is found and so hopefully won't time out. :)

Comment: This solution is not complete. The problem states that a single index cannot be used more than once. Consider the array `[3,2,4]` with a target of `6`. This solution will return `[0,0]` which is invalid.