# How to reduce duplicate outputs in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Currently, I was writing a code with Ruby to find out all the possible combination of numbers which equal to a sum. However, I meet the TLE problem and not all combination come out. The output came out with many duplicate combination such as:

```
sum([39,39,119,79,89,79,79,38,19,127.5,77,29,39,39,40,39,39])= 1009.5
sum([39,39,119,79,89,79,79,38,19,127.5,29,39,77,39,39,40,39])= 1009.5
```

Hope someone can teach me to modify my code in order to reduce the duplicate output and maybe this can help to solve TLE problem.Thanks.
My code:

```
def subset_sum(numbers,target,partial=[])            
  s = partial.inject 0, :+
  puts "sum(#{partial})=#{target}" if s == target

  return if s >= target 

  (0..(numbers.length - 1)).each do |i|
    n = numbers[i]
    remaining = numbers.drop(i+1)
    subset_sum(remaining ,target ,partial +[n]) 
  end 
end


 > subset_sum([19,19,19,39,29,40,38,39,39,39,39,39,79,59,119,119,79,129,129,78,139,69.5,89,77,79,128,98,109,109,138,127.5,119,108,148,118],1009.5)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to optimize the solution for Two\_sum code in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712489/how-to-optimize-the-solution-for-two-sum-code-in-ruby)

Comment: Additionally, I suggest that you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help you get answers in the future.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but my question is to find all the possible combination of numbers which equal to the sum given, the solution in "How to optimize the solution for Two_sum code in ruby" is not appropriate to my question.